# Wrong Calculation Magento shopping cart price rules

Tags: magento

We are encountering a strange miscalculation with our shopping cart price rules.

We have two price rules. One is standard 3% discount for logged in customers and one is 2% additional discount when choose for paying with direct debit.

The standard 3% discount is calculated correctly but when the customer chooses to pay with direct debit Magento calculates about 4.3% instead of the proposed 5%.

Has anyone experienced this before?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento Price rules are applied in defined order.
You have first rule (+3%) it's applied to product.
product price is 0.97 of original price. Now to this price new rule will be applied.
new price = 0.97 - 0.97 * 0.02 = 0.9506
in the end price was changed to 4.94.
Take into account that price is changing.